# What happens when ember's model hook's request fails

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a typical scenario. 
My model hook for `Route-1` looks something like this.

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    posts: this.store.findAll('post'),
    authors: this.store.findAll('author')
  });
 }
```

If I'm on `Route-2` and navigate to `Route-1` it will call the `model` hook.
And if I already have data on my store, both the `findAll` requests are resolved, triggering RSVP.hash to resolve.

But if the request fails, I'm getting `undefined` error in my console (chrome).(twice for each of findAll)
My error tracking system reports it as `Unhandled promise error detected`

the stack shows no relevant info either

```
defaultDispatch @ ember.debug.js:18008  
dispatchError @ ember.debug.js:17987  
onerrorDefault @ ember.debug.js:31634  
trigger @ ember.debug.js:58713  
(anonymous) @ ember.debug.js:59614  
invokeWithOnError @ ember.debug.js:346  
flush @ ember.debug.js:405  
flush @ ember.debug.js:529  
end @ ember.debug.js:599  
(anonymous) @ ember.debug.js:1165
```

I am not able to figure out what is causing the error to be thrown because the promise `findAll` already got resolved. And ember tells me I have not handled the promise!

I tried putting catch/reject codes everywher but it never gets called. Because of course the promise was already resolved. So, it can not be rejected.

Then where is this error coming from!! I have no clue. There is no error till the adapter returns.

The only thing I could find was in my serializer `normalizeFindAllResponse` was not invoked whenever such failures happened.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You may need to look for the adpater and serializer used for loading `post` and `author` model for potential error. Is there any expandable option for stack trace error ? since its not giving any clue actually

Comment: I checked it up. There is no error. The adapter just sends what it gets (in this case rejected `reason`). And the serializer was never called.

Comment: As for the stack trace, it is 'ember's` code which just invokes the error. Has no relevant info I can vouch on that.

Comment: Can you check your server response? Is it a valid json?

Comment: @ykaragol Yep, it has a JSON response. My adapter's promise handler gets executed successfully. And after adapter returns, there is an error thrown in console with no relevant information. It just says `undefined` and the above stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow solved this issue.

Before, in my adapter I was rejecting the promise with Promis' `reason`  object.
Now, in case of error response, I am rather sending an object containing `errors` array, rather then failure reason object.
So, the object will get passed as payload to my `normalizeFindAllResponse` in serializer. There I check for existance of `errors` array in our `payload` parameter.
If there is such object then just return an empty object with `data` attribute set to empty array.

Note: Got the idea from [here](http://thejsguy.com/2016/01/09/handling-errors-with-ember-data.html).